# YA Fantasy Anthology featuring folklore legends in original stories - 80s-90s

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, anthology-book, folklore

I'm looking for YA fantasy anthology from the late 80s, early 90s. I'm pretty sure the cover was black. It featured stories that were based on regional/ethnic folklore. One story that stood out for me was about the Mongolian Siddhi-Kir. Another story was about a Tahitian or Hawaiian god. I believe there was a story about the New Jersey Devil. About 11-13 stories in all.